# How to use variable of other java file in current java file within same package?

Tags: java, extends

I've  `MouseActions.java` file with the driver object of `FirefoxDriver class`.
I've another `keyactions.java` file, and I've extended this class to `MouseActions.java`.

Now I want to use driver object of `MouseActions.java` file in `keyactions.java` file without instantiating a new object.

but I'm getting error "multiple markers at the line"

`MouseActions.java` file:

```
package myproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class mouseOverEvent
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
        Actions Builder=new Actions(driver);
        WebElement home=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[2]"));
        Action mouseOverHome= Builder.moveToElement(home).click().build();
        mouseOverHome.perform();
    }
}
```

`keyactions.java` file:

```
package myproject;

public class KeyStrokesEvent extends mouseOverEvent{    
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");  
}
```

Comment: *"but I'm getting error "multiple markers at the line""* This is not the error message, it just tells you that you have more than one error in one line. So please post the real error messages. Btw: `driver.get("http://www.facebook.com"); ` won't work, since `driver` is undefined and it is outside of a method/block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making the driver variable global?

```
package myproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


public class mouseOverEvent {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
        Actions Builder=new Actions(driver);
        WebElement home=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[2]"));
        Action mouseOverHome= Builder.moveToElement(home).click().build();
        mouseOverHome.perform();
    }
}
```

The variable is local to the method main() that's why you cannot access it outside that method. Making it global however, makes it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

The driver variable is defined in a method, Its scope is limited to the method. It can;t be accessed outside it.

You need to declare it as class level for accessing in your sub class. To access it without creating object, the declare it as `static` variable and access it with class name.

I am wondering why are you extending a Main class into some other class?